# checking for file descriptor to be ready using select so read can proceed in child thread

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, sockets, io

I have the following code. It is using socket connections and assigning them to multiple threads. Then I am using `select()` in order to have active file descriptor(s).

```
void func(void *arg){
    int fd=(int) arg;

    char *buffer[64000];
    struct sockaddr_in saddr_in;
    int in_len;
    while(1){
        recvfrom(fd,buffer,sizeof (buffer),0,&saddr_in,&in_len);
        struct iphdr *h=(struct iphdr *)buffer;
        struct sockaddr_in t;
        t.sin_addr.s_addr=h->saddr;
        char *str=inet_ntoa(t.sin_addr);
        printf("thread %d received %s\n ",fd,str);
    }
}

void main()
{
    pthread_t t1,t2;
    int fd1 = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_TCP);
    int fd2 = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_TCP);
    int nfds=fd2+1;
    struct timeval *pto;
    struct timeval timeout;
    pto = &timeout;
    timeout.tv_sec = 10;
    timeout.tv_usec = 0;
    /* No microseconds */
    int one = 1;
    const int *val = &one;
    if(setsockopt(fd1, IPPROTO_IP, IP_HDRINCL, val, sizeof(one)) < 0)
    {
        perror("setsockopt() error");
        exit(-1);
    }
    if(setsockopt(fd2, IPPROTO_IP, IP_HDRINCL, val, sizeof(one)) < 0)
    {
        perror("setsockopt() error");
        exit(-1);
    }
    fd_set readfds;
    FD_ZERO(&readfds);
    FD_SET(fd1, &readfds);
    FD_SET(fd2, &readfds);

    pthread_create(&t1,NULL,func,fd1);
    pthread_create(&t2,NULL,func,fd2);

    select(nfds, &readfds,  NULL, NULL,NULL);
    while(1)
    {
        printf("Main\n");sleep(1);
        select(nfds, &readfds,  NULL, NULL,NULL);
    };
}
```

I would like to know, in the above scenario, is `select()` actually needed? I think it is not going to make any difference, unless in the `main()` function after the `select()` call (means when one of the file descriptors is ready for I/O), I have some way of finding which file descriptor is ready for I/O. If I am interested in that information, how can I check which file descriptor is ready for I/O so I can print something useful in the main thread instead of using `printf()` in the child threads?

Comment: Finding the FD that's ready is all you want? So why the multithreading? That doesn't make your question much clearer.

Comment: Either use a `select()`+`recv/from()` loop in the main thread, or let `recv/from()` block a worker thread. It doesn’t make sense to use both approaches. Also, `select()` will modify `readfds` so you need to reset it each time you call `select()`.

Comment: Unless you are coding for a freestanding environment, revisit the use of `void main()`.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt my question should have been why not multi threading if multiple socket connections can give more reliable results in terms of catching all the packets on NIC card. does it make sense? or I am misleading myself. I would like to know in any circumstance is it possible packet(s)  that are not captured by fd1 connection can and more probably (more likely) be caught by fd2 connection.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin what do u mean by `withstanding environment`? please clearify

Comment: can anyone please explain how real-world mutithreaded servers are implemented. they use `multithreading` right? and they also use `multiplexing` using select/poll/epoll. I like to related my question with this comment.?

Comment: Unless you are programming in a *freestanding environment* (without the benefit of any OS), in a standards conforming implementation, the allowable declarations for `main` for are `int main (void)` and `int main (int argc, char *argv[])` (which you will see written with the equivalent `char **argv`).  See: [C11 Standard - §5.1.2.2.1 Program startup(p1)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.1.2.2.1p1). See also: [What should main() return in C and C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/204476/) In a freestanding environment, the name and type of startup are implementation-defined.

Comment: Yes, in the real word, multithreading servers use threads, either pthread for Linux or the windows equivalent there. However, just chopping a program up into threads doesn't automatically help the program performance. What the threads do must be able to be done by separate processes (for the most part). Coordinating between multiple threads isn't trivial, see Consider [5 Big Fat Reasons Why Mutexes Suck Big Time](https://accu.org/var/uploads/journals/Overload149.pdf) (2nd Article) How you coordinate among threads can very. Shared memory, sockets, etc.. But they all have to work together.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin is embedded server development also `freestanding environment`?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin can you please look at this question if u can help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65378401/how-to-assign-incoming-packets-source-port-to-outgoing-packet-destination-port

Comment: @RemyLebeau reset and also reassign `readfds`?

Comment: @Alex you are thinking of “reset” as meaning “clearing”. I was thinking of “reset” as meaning “recreating” or “re-preparing”. But yes, you need to clear `readfds` and re-add the desired socket descriptor(s) to it.

Comment: @Alex, think of it this way. If you are embedding a sever on a microcontroller and you are working on bare-metal so you provide the entire code -- then yes, that is a *freestanding environment*. If on the other hand, your microcontroller is running RTOS, and that is providing interrupt handling for you, then that isn't a freestanding environment, it is a hosted environment.

Answer (score 0):

`select` returns number of file descriptors which are ready. In a loop we can check which file descriptor(s) were/was ready using FD_ISSET(..) to see if current loop indexed file descriptor is in 3 fd sets returned by select. On success select returns ready file descriptors by re-assigning fds to readfds,writefds,errfds as passed argument. for that I have to made some changes to my code by including `&` as `&readfds` since we have to pass the address to get 'em reassigned.

note: not accepting this answer since I am looking for more details like are two socket connections can prove to be more reliable since if first socket missed an incoming packet then second socket more likely catch it. also what real world servers do with multithreading, threads communication(like packets related info if one thread received a `sync` flag packet so letting other threads know same thread will send `syn+ack`), the use of mutexes to protect shared resources, and use of multiplexing like select/poll/epoll