# How to assign incoming packet's source port to outgoing packet destination port -- TCP C Linux

Tags: c, linux, tcp, port, raw-sockets

I like to know the source port of packet in tcphdr can be assigned to destination port of ip like this

```
       source_ip_tcph->source= dest_ip_tcph->dest;
       source_ip_tcph->dest  = dest_ip_tcph->source;
```

above are source and destination (pointer to memory) of tcphdr type

I am trying to create a server everytime I respond to client from server the destination port is different. I assigned it like above

**Edit**
Above I am using raw sockets. trying to make raw socket based tcp implementation as a server

Comment: Are you using raw sockets? What is the actual problem you need to solve? Why do you think this is the (only) solution to that problem?

Comment: I don't really understand what you are trying to achieve. I think you need to add more detail and context.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I have added more details

Comment: https://lwip.fandom.com/wiki/IPv4